# Make a turn based system like final fantasy tactics AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

i wanted to make a turn based system like final fantasy tactics. I already created the map, which is 5x5 tiles grid and the characters which is each character places in the end of the tiles. I have 2 teams, which are named `Red` and `Yellow`.

`------Red-------:`

First character is at `0,0`. Second character is at `0,1. Third character is at`0.2`, fourth character is at`0.3`, and the last one is at`0.4`.

`-----Yellow------:`

First character is at `5.0`. Second character is at `5.1`. Third character is at `5.2`, fourth character is at `5.3`, and the last one is at `5.4`.

I wanted `Red` team are moving first and make a decision (whether it is attack or wait), and after 5 characters of the `Red` team is already made a decision, the `Yellow` team is the one that make a decision (`Yellow` team is an AI)

But, i don't know how to move my characters into the next grid (e.g: from 0,0 to 0,1) by clicking the left mouse button and also how do i display a grid (when select a move selection) that shows how many tiles that the character able to move.

Anyone know about this? or how should i know more about this? is there any recommendations books or webs?

Answer (score 1):

You have your basic data structures set up, but now you need to get some higher level code to manipulate that data.

First of all, I think you should work on selecting locations on the grid with the mouse. Once you can click and get that grid coordinate saved to a variable, you need to set up a function to move your characters. After the first click (on a character), you need to check the valid moves, and for each valid move, you need to render an image on the grid square (or highlight the square's texture).

Secondly, you need a function which iterates through all the characters in each team, according to who moves next. When you have gone through Red.length (red is an array consisting of each player), then you switch to counting through Yellow.length, and running the AI for each character. If you are trying to make a two player game, you instead ask for user input a second time for the yellow team.

I recommend that you learn about how to display your grid and set up a simple way to highlight squares on the grid. After that, you need to convert mouse coordinates into grid coordinates. Your teams should each be an array of characters. I'm not familiar with actionscript, but in the languages I know, they would look like this:

```
team[6] = {Character1, Character2, Character3... }
Character1.position = {x, y}
```

running a turn would be something like this:

```
while battle == not finished {
    for (i = 0; i < red.length; i++) {
        getInput();
        move(red[i], newX, newY); //red[i].position = {newX, newY}
    }
    for (i = 0; i < yellow.length; i++) {
        runAI();
        move(yellow[i], newX, newY);
    }
}
```

The hardest part will be the mouse selection and drawing the grid/characters. Graphics are always a nuisance. The data itself just takes a bit of thinking. Your question in particular seems to be about game programming. My advice is to make the grid, then figure out how to display the grid. Then get mouse input. Finally, worry about moving the characters and highlighting squares.